# Return value from range which can be found within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with exports of email messages, with columns for Subject, Sender, Body, etc. I also have a worksheet with a column of strings I would expect to find in those emails, and another column classifying them.

What I am trying to do is add a column to the first sheet with those classifications by matching the strings to the email bodies and then returning the classification.

Right now the only means I have come up with is a very long if-else statement, iterating over each classification.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E2,"*"&Exceptions!A$1&"*"),Exceptions!C$1,IF(COUNTIF(E2,"*"&Exceptions!A$2&"*"),Exceptions!C$2,IF(COUNTIF(E2,"*"&Exceptions!A$3&"*"),Exceptions!C$3,IF(COUNTIF(E2,"*"&Exceptions!A$4&"*"),Exceptions!C$4,IF(COUNTIF(E2,"*"&Exceptions!A$5&"*"),Exceptions!C$5)))))
```

Its not great fun when you have 50+ if() statements in one formula! I'd obviously prefer something more dynamic for both readability and so I can add/remove strings/classifications from the sheet without rewriting the formua.

Any help would be much appreciated.

So I have a column with email messages:

```
Hey guys, meeting was rescheduled for 3PM....
Following up on that earlier conference call....
Can I have a lead time for....
```

I also have a table with expected strings and classifications

```
lead time                      Lead Time
conference call                Conference
meeting wasrescheduled         Rescheduled Meeting
```

The goal is to produce something like

```
Rescheduled Meeting   Hey guys, meeting was rescheduled for 3PM....
Conference            Following up on that earlier conference call....
Lead Time             Can I have a lead time for....
```

The formula I'm using uses COUNTIF() to compare the message, E2, with the table of strings (Exceptions!A:A) and classifications (Exceptions!C:C). If the string is found within message, COUNTIF() returns 1 and the IF() statement evaluates as true. When the IF() statement evaluates true, the classification is returned. If false, the next IF() statement is checked, using the next row of data from the string/classification table.

Comment: Can you try breaking down your current if statement for the question, and perhaps post some examples? I think I see what you're looking for, but it's hard to tell without seeing the excel file, and reading a very long horizontal if statement. If you're able to post at least one example and your expected output I may be able to help.

Comment: I've edited my question to include some examples and explain the current formula better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the SEARCH() function to determine whether each string is present in the email, and apply the classification if the result is non-null (SEARCH returns the position of the string within the text you are searching. Not sure if that makes your overall solution easier to achieve, but it's easier than your current approach using COUNTIF.

I'd also consider using COUNTIFS as an alternative to stringing multiple COUNTIF functions together in this way.